# org mode - prevent future repetitive entries from showing up in agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

It seems to be obvious but I don't seem to have been able to find an answer yet... I have some repetitive tasks which have a property in the style of `SCHEDULED: <2015-05-22 Fri 23:00 .+4d>`. However this has the effect of making that task also showing up on the agenda view of May 26, May 30... etc. etc., which clutters up the agenda view significantly. I notice that scheduled entries with `habit` style don't behave like this, however I don't want to make all repetitive tasks into `habit`. There must be a way to prevent future occurrences of repetitive tasks(Both `DEADLINE` and `SCHEDULED`) from showing up on calendar prematurely?

Comment: How about customizing the variable `org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all`?:  "*Non-nil means show all occurrences of a repeating stamp in the agenda.  When set to a list of strings, only show occurrences of repeating  stamps for these TODO keywords.  **When `nil`, only one occurrence is  shown, either today or the nearest into the future.***"  I've never tried this, but it looks like it might be applicable since the default value is `t`.

Comment: @lawlist Cool. That's the right variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default value for the variable `org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all` is `t` -- i.e., "*Non-nil means show all occurrences of a repeating stamp in the agenda.*"  The variable can be set to "*a list of strings*" to "*only show occurrences of repeating stamps for these TODO keywords*." When the variable is set to `nil`, "*only one occurrence is shown, either today or the nearest into the future.*"  Therefore, the original poster may wish to add the following line to the `.emacs` or `init.el` file:

```
(setq org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all nil)
```

Comment: org-mode 9.1, currently in development, has removed `org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all`.  For purposes of this question, I believe the replacement setting is in `org-agenda-show-future-repeats`.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR:** `(setq org-agenda-show-future-repeats nil)`.

---

You have to set `org-agenda-show-future-repeats` to `nil`. The previous option `org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all` [has been removed from Org mode in version 9.1](https://www.orgmode.org/Changes_old.html#org346f28d), as the new pair of options—the previously named `org-agenda-show-future-repeats` and `org-agenda-prefer-last-repeat`—provide a more fine grained control over the shown tasks in the agenda.

Note that `org-agenda-show-future-repeats` also supports `next` if you want to show a single future repeat. For more information, see `M-x customize-option org-agenda-show-future-repeats`.